# Columns generation for levels from factor variables by aggregating conditionally using group by in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, conditional-statements, aggregate

To the below data frame, I am trying to create eight additional columns Last1Col7activ to Last10Col7inactive conditionally from FactorCol1:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data_Frame <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3"),
                         
                         Col2 = c("2011-03-11", "2014-08-21", "2016-01-17", "2017-06-30", "2018-07-11", "2018-11-28", "2019-09-04", "2020-02-29", "2020-07-12"),
                         
                         Col3 = c("2018-10-22", "2019-05-24", "2020-12-25", "2018-10-12", "2019-09-24", "2020-12-19", "2018-10-22", "2019-06-14", "2020-12-20"),
                         
                         Col4 = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                         
                         Col5 = c(7, 6, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2),
                         
                         FactorCol1 = c("active", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "active", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "inactive"),
                         
                         FactorCol2 = c("Level2", "Level2", "Level3", "Level1", "Level3", "Level1", "Level2", "Level1", "Level3"))

Data_Frame$Col1 <- as.factor(Data_Frame$Col1)
Data_Frame$Col2 <- as.Date(Data_Frame$Col2)
Data_Frame$Col3 <- as.Date(Data_Frame$Col3)
Data_Frame$FactorCol1 <- as.factor(Data_Frame$FactorCol1)
Data_Frame$FactorCol2 <- as.factor(Data_Frame$FactorCol2)

Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% mutate(Col6 = lubridate::time_length(lubridate::interval(Col2, max(Col3)), "years"))
Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% dplyr::mutate(Col7 = ifelse(Col6 <= 1, 1, ifelse(Col6 >1 & Col6 <=2, 2, ifelse(Col6 >2 & Col6 <=5, 5, ifelse(Col6 >5 & Col6 <=10, 10, 11)))))

Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% dplyr::mutate(Col8 = ifelse(FactorCol1 == 'active', 1, 0))
Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% dplyr::mutate(Col9 = ifelse(FactorCol1 == 'inactive', 1, 0))

Data_Frame <- as.data.frame(Data_Frame)

Data_Frame <- map_dfc(c(1, 2, 5, 10), ~ Data_Frame %>%
          group_by(Col1) %>% 
          transmute(!! sprintf("Last%dCol7active", .x) := ifelse(((Col7 <= .x)), sum(Col8 == 1),0),
                    !! sprintf("Last%dCol7inactive", .x) := ifelse(((Col7 <= .x)), sum(Col9 == 1),0)) %>% 
          ungroup %>%
          select(-Col1)) %>% 
          bind_cols(Data_Frame, .)
```

In the above,

Col6: time difference between max(Col3) and Col2 within each group

Col7: (<=) years for the values in Col6

Col8: active elements in FactorCol1 set as 1

Col9: inactive elements in FactorCol1 set as 1

Last1Col7active: Within each group (A1 to A3 in Col1), number of active elements in FactorCol1 that are <=1 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of active elements within the group

Last1Col7inactive: Within each group, number of inactive elements in FactorCol1 that are <=1 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of inactive elements within the group

Last5Col7active: Within each group (A1 to A3 in Col1), number of active elements in FactorCol1 that are <=5 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of active elements within the group

Last5Col7inactive: Within each group, number of inactive elements in FactorCol1 that are <=5 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of inactive elements within the group

Last10Col7active: Within each group (A1 to A3 in Col1), number of active elements in FactorCol1 that are <=10 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of active elements within the group

Last10Col7inactive: Within each group, number of inactive elements in FactorCol1 that are <=10 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of inactive elements within the group

The expected result is:
[image]

However, the output is:
[image]

What is going wrong? And, is there a way to generate these columns automatically without typing in the name of the levels in transmute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `ifelse`. It is just a small simplification of your function:

```r
Data_Frame <- map_dfc(c(1, 2, 5, 10), ~ Data_Frame %>%
                          group_by(Col1) %>% 
                          transmute(!! sprintf("Last%dCol7active", .x) := sum(Col8[Col7 <= .x]),
                                    !! sprintf("Last%dCol7inactive", .x) := sum(Col9[Col7 <= .x])) %>% 
                          ungroup %>%
                          select(-Col1)) %>% 
    bind_cols(Data_Frame, .)
  Col1       Col2       Col3 Col4 Col5 FactorCol1 FactorCol2      Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Last1Col7active Last1Col7inactive Last2Col7active Last2Col7inactive Last5Col7active Last5Col7inactive
1   A1 2011-03-11 2018-10-22    4    7     active     Level2 9.7917808   10    1    0               0                 0               0                 0               0                 1
2   A1 2014-08-21 2019-05-24    2    6   inactive     Level2 6.3452055   10    0    1               0                 0               0                 0               0                 1
3   A1 2016-01-17 2020-12-25    2    3   inactive     Level3 4.9371585    5    0    1               0                 0               0                 0               0                 1
4   A2 2017-06-30 2018-10-12    1    1     active     Level1 3.4712329    5    1    0               0                 0               0                 0               2                 1
5   A2 2018-07-11 2019-09-24    4    3     active     Level3 2.4410959    5    1    0               0                 0               0                 0               2                 1
6   A2 2018-11-28 2020-12-19    4    2   inactive     Level1 2.0575342    5    0    1               0                 0               0                 0               2                 1
7   A3 2019-09-04 2018-10-22    4    5   inactive     Level2 1.2931507    2    0    1               1                 1               1                 2               1                 2
8   A3 2020-02-29 2019-06-14    4    1     active     Level1 0.8060109    1    1    0               1                 1               1                 2               1                 2
9   A3 2020-07-12 2020-12-20    4    2   inactive     Level3 0.4410959    1    0    1               1                 1               1                 2               1                 2
  Last10Col7active Last10Col7inactive
1                1                  2
2                1                  2
3                1                  2
4                2                  1
5                2                  1
6                2                  1
7                1                  2
8                1                  2
9                1                  2
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, is there a way to generate the columns automatically based on the levels of FactorCol1?

Comment: I am not sure of your goal. I would say a nested `map_dfc`, so something like `map_dfc(c(1, 2, 5, 10), function(.x) map_dfc(levels(Data_Frame$FactorCol1), function(.y) Data_Frame %>%
            group_by(Col1) %>% 
            transmute(!! sprintf("Last%dCol7%s", .x, .y) := sum(Col8[Col7 <= .x]),
                      !! sprintf("Last%dCol7%s", .x, .y) := sum(Col9[Col7 <= .x])) ...`?

Comment: I am not sure what is `Data_Frame` in your comment (in which step of your question are you?), so what is `K`? Maybe this is subject for another question...